# What brand is this faucet?

Tags: kitchens, faucet

I need a replacement handle for this faucet, but I don't know the brand. Any info would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A few more pictures might help. If you can't post the pictures, post the URLs and someone will be along to edit in the pictures.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a KWC (Swiss), possibly of the Domo or [Systema](http://www.kwc.com/english/products/series-overview/linie-detail/line/kwc-systema-4.html#22366) lines. Here's a [replacement sprayer](http://www.decorisland.com/product/kwc/z-504-212-127/spray-head-for-9-pull-out-faucets-7-spout-reach/stainless-steel/?detailsfeed=yes#feeddetails) (for reference only). Judging by the poor web presence it's probably from before or around the turn of the century.

Comment: Yes, it was installed in 1999.  I'll check those brands out.  Thanks.